# Can't get grid_remove() to work

Tags: python, tkinter

In the app I'm working on I have a class setup to handle all my GUI.  One method in this class creates a frame and populates a group of radiobutton's from a loop.  This method will be called multiple times from outside the class to redraw this frame.  The problem I have is that when the frame is redrawn it is actually just overwriting the existing frame (old frame persists).  So if there are fewer options in a later call, the earlier options are still visible.  I have tried doing a grid_remove on the frame first but can't get that to work.  So my question is, why is the grid_remove() not working in the initMech() method below?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

   from Tkinter import *

   class MWindow(Frame):
       def __init__(self, parent) :
           Frame.__init__(self, parent)
           self.parent = parent
           self.initUI()

       def initUI(self):
           topframe = Frame(self.parent, bd=2, relief=GROOVE, padx=5, pady=5, width=300, height=50)
           topframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
           desc = Button(topframe, text="list1", command=lambda:set_list(1))
           desc.grid(row=0,column=1)
           desc2 = Button(topframe, text="list2", command=lambda:set_list(2))
           desc2.grid(row=0,column=2)

       def initMech(self):
           try:
               radio_frame.grid_remove()
           except:
               print "can't remove"
           radio_frame = Frame(self.parent, bd=2, relief=GROOVE, padx=5, pady=5, width=300, height=50)
           radio_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
           variant=StringVar()
           c = 0
           for x in chas.v_list:
               Radiobutton(radio_frame, text=x,variable=variant, value=x, command=lambda x = x:chas.set_vari(x)).grid(row=0, column=c)
               c = c+1

       def onExit(self):
           self.parent.destroy()

   class Mech():
       def set_chass(self,chass):
           try:
               if self.chassis == chass:
                   pass
               else:
                   self.chassis = chass
                   del self.vari
           except AttributeError:
               self.chassis = chass

       def load_vari(self):
           if self.chassis == 1:
               self.v_list = ["a","b","c"]
           else:
               self.v_list = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
           win.initMech()

       def set_vari(self, vari):
           self.vari = vari

   def set_list(num):
       chas.set_chass(num)
       chas.load_vari()

   root = Tk()
   win = MWindow(root)
   chas = Mech()
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you're using a local variable named `radio_frame`, and that variable isn't defined yet. Most likely, the error message you are ignoring is telling you exactly that. Why are you trying to remove a frame that you haven't yet created?

Also, are you aware that `grid_remove` only removes the widget from view, it doesn't destroy it? Thus, if you call this function several times you'll have several invisible versions of this frame, all using up memory.